# Why is this set uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of all pairs $(A,<)$, where $A\subset \Bbb Z_+$ and $<$ is well ordering of $A$. (We allow $A$ to be empty) Define $(A,<)\sim(A',<')$ if $(A,<)$ and $(A',<')$ have the same order type. Let $[(A,<)]$ denote the equivalence class of $(A,<)$ ; let $E$ denote the collection of these equivalence classes. Define $[(A,<)] \ll [(A',<')]$ if $(A,<)$ has order type of a *section* of $(A',<')$.

Isn't $E=\{[(\varnothing,\varnothing)]\}\bigcup\cup_{n=1}^\infty\{[(\{1,2,\dots,n\},<)]\}\bigcup\{[(\Bbb Z_+,<)]\}$, hence countable?

(This question is from Munkres Topology.)

Comment: The set all tuples isn't countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $E$ contains many more order types than the ones you show. Let $\omega$ = the ordinal that is the order type of $\Bbb Z_+$. Where is $\omega+1$ in your list? (This is the order type of $\{1/n\mid n\in \Bbb Z_+\}$? Where is $\omega + \omega$, the order type of two copies of $\omega$ in a row?  For every countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is an ordering in $E$ of order type $\alpha$, and there are uncountably many countable ordinals.

Answer (score 3):

No, $E$ has one equivalence class for each countable well-order type. This includes the countably infinite types. The simplest of these is $[\langle\Bbb Z_+,<\rangle]$. Another can be obtained by letting $m\prec n$ if and only if either $m$ is even and $n$ is odd, or $m$ and $n$ have the same parity and $m<n$. The resulting well-order on $\Bbb Z_+$ looks like this:

$$2,4,6,8,\ldots,1,3,5,7,\ldots\;.$$

$[\langle\Bbb Z_+,\prec\rangle]$ is a member of $E$ distinct from any that we've already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for such clear explanation.

Comment: @Silent: You're welcome.